# Disable a trigger from a trigger Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I've stumbled on a situation where I need to disable a trigger from a trigger before doing an update, and then renable it.

Basically, I have two tables:

- `TIME_SLOTS` has fields such as start time, end time, to set the time
  slot for a programme as well as programme ID (foreign key) to specify
  which program.
- `PROGRAMMES` contains a list of all the different available programs
  & their details. Also contains a duration.

I have an existing trigger that, when updating or inserting to `TIME_SLOTS`, the trigger lookups the duration from `PROGRAMMES` and ensures that End Time = Start Time + Duration.

I also want to add a new trigger that updates the End Time in `TIME_SLOTS` when changing the duration in `PROGRAMMES`.

I have set these two triggers up, but when changing the duration I get:

```
One error saving changes to table "SE217"."PROGRAMMES":
Row 1: ORA-04091: table SE217.PROGRAMMES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SE217.SCHEDULES_VALID_TIMES", line 19
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SE217.SCHEDULES_VALID_TIMES'
ORA-06512: at "SE217.UPDATE_END_TIME", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SE217.UPDATE_END_TIME'
```

This is obviously because when I change the duration, the 2nd trigger goes to update the end time in `TIME_SLOTS`. The trigger on `TIME_SLOTS` fires and looks up the duration - the duration is mutating and I get the error as above.

It seems to me that when I update the `TIME_SLOTS` row with the newly calculated end time, I should just disable the trigger before and renable after the update - but as this is trigger I can't alter a trigger...

Any ideas?

EDIT: I had a thought that I could set a global variable and check this var in the trigger that I don't want to run etc - but wasn't sure how best to implement?

Comment: IMHO, using a package variable is a good choice.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Can you store triggers in packages? How would this work?

Comment: Variable should be stored in a package.

Comment: No, you can't store triggers in a package but you should have warnings flashing in front of your face. Disabling triggers inside triggers is never the correct option and the error you're getting is indicative of not having a properly normalised database. @Egor is suggesting that you remove all the logic from your triggers and place it in a package instead, which is often the way around this error.

Comment: You're doing two unpopular and generally frowned-on things here: using triggers for anything other than auditing activities, and storing redundant data (ie denormalising).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can almost certainly disable one trigger from another using an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name_here DISABLE';
```

However, you definitely shouldn't be using triggers for application logic. It's a messy business, not least due to the fact that triggers aren't guaranteed to fire in order, but also because of the kind of "problem" you're experiencing.

It would be much easier and significantly safer to move *all* of the functionality you described to a stored procedure or package, and use triggers only where necessary for validation purposes.

Comment: I sort of understand what you mean but don't really get how to implement this. Surely I need a trigger to update the other table when the first gets changed? Are you suggesting calling the procedure in the trigger or?

Comment: What we're all suggesting is that instead of directly issuing an INSERT or UPDATE statement against the first table and then relying on a trigger to update the second, you should simply call a stored procedure to INSERT/UPDATE both tables as necessary and not use triggers for this purpose at all.

Comment: @swiss196: what we're suggesting is that you have a procedure which you call which implements ***all*** the logic needed to update your data, including cross-table updates, etc. The number of ways this kind of multi-trigger logic can go wrong are astronomical. For example, consider how this will work in a multi-transaction environment. If you think a mutating table issue is difficult to correct, I will absolutely guarantee that keeping your triggers coordinated is going to be worse. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Those kinds of problems occurs when you have to customize an existing functionality and you just have full control on database. So you are not able to replace the inserts/updates by a procedure, you can just react. In this situation you have triggers on both tables and propagate values between the tables in both directions.